# How to extract keys and values from a multiple dictionaries file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a file that contains multiple dictionaries such that,
`newfile = {"votes": {"funny": 0, "useful": 5, "cool": 2}, "user_id": "rLtl8ZkDX5vH5nAx9C3q5Q", "review_id": "fWKvX83p0-ka4JS3dc6E5A", "stars": 5, "date": "2011-01-26"}
{"votes": {"funny": 0, "useful": 0, "cool": 0}, "user_id": "0a2KyEL0d3Yb1V6aivbIuQ", "review_id": "IjZ33sJrzXqU-0X6U8NwyA", "stars": 5, "date": "2011-07-27"}`

This file is stored in my drive, i need to read each record line by line from file and want to print values for each key such as,

```
print newfile['votes'] = {"funny": 0, "useful": 5, "cool": 2} for first line
print newfile['votes'] = {"funny": 0, "useful": 0, "cool": 0} for second line
```

Comment: Does each line in the file represent exactly one dictionary?

Comment: It looks like a JSON file.  Could it be a JSON file?  Should it be a JSON file?  How did you create it?

Comment: @WombatPM if it quacks like a duck and types like a duck...

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, each line in file represents multiple dictionaries.

Comment: @WombatPM, it is not completely json file, actually each line represents a multiple dictionary. This file is from a benchmark data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read the file line by line, such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277512/141789

Then, parse the text as json strings (presuming the individual lines are in valid json format, if not your problem has become much more difficult).

```
import json
dicts = []
for line in array:
    dicts.append(json.loads(line))
```

If the entire file is in json format it's much easier. In that case it would look like `[{...},{...}]`. I.e the dictionaries are enclosed within square brackets (list of dictionaries) and separated by a comma.

Just look for "read from json" and you'll find tons of examples of how this can be read